# Toggle script execution when clicked on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a script to hide the navigation on scroll down and to show up again on scroll up a little.
But on mobile I need to stop this, if the hamburger button is clicked.

How can I achieve this? Here ist the code for the navigation hide / show:

```html
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('.pageheader').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('.pageheader').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('.pageheader').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }
    
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be several solutions depending on what you're really trying to achieve:

### Solution 1

Store the state of the hamburger button whether it is open or closed in a variable and simply exit your `hasScrolled` function:

```js
var isMenuOpen = false;

// then toggle the value of isMenuOpen whenever clicking the hamburger button

function hasScrolled() {
    // do nothing and exit if the menu is open
    if (isMenuOpen) {
        return;
    }

    // the rest of the function
}
```

### Solution 2

You can also toggle the scrolling on your page with the following CSS (assuming that the scrollable content that you're watching is `document.body`):

```js
hamburgerMenuClickListener() {
    // based on the logic of your menu you might need to customize this line
    document.body.classList.toggle("noScroll");

    // other logic of your code
}
```

```css
body.noScroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: there are 2 naive solutions from the top of my head without knowing the details of your app logic, which will impact what solution will fit your needs

Comment: Thank you! I prefer solution 2, because it is very simple. But I guess, i will get a problem on IOS devices. But I will check it out.

Comment: @JPC yes on mobile devices there might be some pitfalls with scrolling